# How to apply a function to a list within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and a function:

```
t = [3, [1], [2, [1], [1]]]

f = lambda x: x**2
```

I want the result like this:

```
[9, [1], [4, [1], [1]]]
```

I tried to use map function but it did not seem to work

I got a type error when I do this:

```
list(map(f, t))
```

Comment: Your lambda needs to check the type of its input arg and do something different for a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your function to be recursive so that it can traverse data of an arbitrary depth:

```
f = lambda x:x*x if not isinstance(x, list) else [f(i) for i in x]
t = [3, [1], [2, [1], [1]]]
new_result = list(map(f, t))
```

Output:

```
[9, [1], [4, [1], [1]]]
```

Comment: I would have used `i*i` instead of `pow(i,2)`, otherwise nice

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That is much cleaner. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: is there a way without changing the function

Comment: @ChengmingGu You will still need to use recursion to reach the integer values in the nested lists. See Aran-Fey's solution, which applies your original function to every integer, regardless of depth.

Answer (score 7):

if the element of `t` is another list, you need to map the function, not call the function. If you want this to handle arbitrary levels of nesting, `f` needs to be recursive.

```
t = [3, [1], [2, [1], [1]]]

def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return map(f, x)
    else:
        return x**2

print(map(f, t))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a recursion function and a list comprehension as following:

```
def nested_pow(arr, p):
   return [pow(i, p) if isinstance(i, int) else nested_pow(i, p) for i in arr]
```

Demo:

```
In [34]: nested_pow(t, 2)
Out[34]: [9, [1], [4, [1], [1]]]

In [35]: nested_power(t, 3)
Out[35]: [27, [1], [8, [1], [1]]]

In [36]: nested_power(t, 10)
Out[36]: [59049, [1], [1024, [1], [1]]]
```

Comment: I would have used `i*i` instead of `pow(i,2)`, otherwise nice

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes that'd be much more optimize. But for larger powers mmm not a good trade ;).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No thanks for mentioning that because as I said it's faster to directly multiply than calling the `pow` it's useful in cases that the power is always a small number and fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a recursive variant of the `map` function:

```
def recursive_map(func, iterable, *, sequence_types=(list,tuple)):
    for value in iterable:
        # if's a sequence, recurse
        if isinstance(value, sequence_types):
            cls = type(value)
            values = recursive_map(func, value, sequence_types=sequence_types)
            yield cls(values)
        else:  # if it's not a sequence, call the function on it
            yield func(value)
```

```
t = [3, [1], [2, [1], [1]]]
f = lambda x: x**2

print(list(recursive_map(f, t)))
# output: [9, [1], [4, [1], [1]]]
```